# Compare select-string piped result against a string

Tags: powershell

I want to compare grep a like Select-String result against a string and return a Boolean true or false, but I can't match the right syntax when I put everything in the if/else expressions.

The error output that I get is:

> At line:1 char:102
>   + ... Object {$_ | Select-String 1 packages found.}) -eq 1 packages found.) ...
>   +                                                          ~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token 'packages' in expression or statement. At line:1
>   char:102
>   + ... Object {$_ | Select-String 1 packages found.}) -eq 1 packages found.) ...
>   +                                                          ~~~~~~~~ Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement. At line:1
>   char:117
>   + ... $_ | Select-String 1 packages found.}) -eq 1 packages found.) { echo  ...
>   +                                                                 ~ Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement. At line:1 char:184
>   + ... rometheus-wmi-exporter is already installed, skipping. } else { c:/pr ...
>   +                                                              ~~~~ Unexpected token 'else' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

If I run the contents of the first expression I get the result as I expect it, but I fail to return a Boolean true or false when I put it in the expression part of the if.

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command --% "if ((choco list prometheus-wmi-exporter | Where-Object {$_ | Select-String "1 packages found."}) -eq "1 packages found.") { echo "prometheus-wmi-ex
porter is already installed, skipping." } else { c:/programdata/chocolatey/bin/choco.exe install --force -y prometheus-wmi-exporter.install }"
```

My end goal is if I get a match to return true, else to return false and execute the false statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your  command doesn't check what you expect, it just retuns if such a package exists,
   not if it is installed `-local`
2. the question is tagged [powershell] but you invoke powershell? Is this supposed to run from a batch? If so why not just use `clist.exe` (shortcut for choco list) and find to check?

```
clist -local|find /i "prometheus-wmi-exporter" &&(echo installed)||(echo not installed)
```

3. the command is overly complex, an if with choco output checked with a `-(not)match` should suffice.

```
if((clist -local) -match 'prometheus-wmi-exporter'){"installed"}else{"not installed"}
```

4. before wrapping the command test it directly

Comment: 1. Thanks, that was intended originally to be list --local-only, but after many tries I pushed without the local-only and it would make things meaningless. 2. It should be run through .ebextensions config file at Elastic Beanstalk deploy time, from container command. 3-4 I ended using based on your suggestion the following:     command: `powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "if ((clist --local-only) -match 'prometheus-wmi-exporter') { echo 'Skipping installation.' } else { c:/programdata/chocolatey/bin/choco.exe install -y prometheus-wmi-exporter.install }"`

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting like this:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "if (choco prometheus-wmi-exporter | Select-String '1 packages found.') { echo 'prometheus-wmi-exporter is already installed, skipping.' } else { c:/programdata/chocolatey/bin/choco.exe install --force -y prometheus-wmi-exporter.install }"
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately I have hit the else clause when there is a match, based on that single quote reference though the following worked out:  powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "if ((choco list prometheus-wmi-exporter | Where-Object {`$_ | Select-String '1 packages found.'}) -eq '1 packages found.') { echo test-true } else { c:/programdata/chocolatey/bin/choco.exe install --force -y prometheus-wmi-exporter.install }"